# Define formula of Countif in Excel VBA, not working

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, formula, countif

I really appreciate if anyone could help; I've been working on this for a while...

I just want to define the formula of countif in a cell, here is the code:

Range("E" & PLrowstart).Formula = "= CountIf($B$PLrowstart:$B$PLrowend" & ",B2)"

PLrowstart and PLrowend are integer variables I set before the line. The range for count if is range("B" & PLrowstart & ":B" & PLrowend). I've also tried other ways, none worked...

TIA.

Comment: Is your formula correct when you type it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Range("E" & PLrowstart).Formula = "= CountIf($B$" & PLrowstart & ":$B$" & PLrowend & ",B2)"
```

Comment: OMG, thank you so much! Can I ask one more question? I've also tried:  Range("E" & PLrowstart).Formula = "= CountIf(Range(Cells(" & PLrowstart & ",2),Cells(" & PLrowend & ",2)),Cells(2,2))"    In excel, it could show the formula right in text, which is like = countif(Range(Cells(2,2), Cells(10,2),Cells(2,2)), however, it doesn 't operate, do you have any clue on this?

Comment: Range and Cells are VBA methods. Accordingly, they will not operate as a formula in a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub SetFormula()


PLrowstart = 2
PLrowend = 4

Range("E" & PLrowstart).Formula = "=CountIf($B$" & PLrowstart & ":$B$" & PLrowend & ",B2)"


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Is "$" necessary?